# Intellij IDEA Java Gradle Project Running

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I got a project that build from gradle, the JARs I need already in the external libraries, and when I coding I CAN call the method that from the JAR and there is no error hint at all, but when I make or run the project, then I got a bunch of errors.There are screenshots that show my problem:
1.Gradle setting and no coding error:
[Gradle setting and no coding error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xeqlC.png)
[image]

2.External libraries and running error:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, till now I fixed the problem just when I use the command line to build the project.

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can try to do a fix in the

`File | Project Structure|Problem`

And click the button fix and click OK and then you remake your projet

Comment: Or maybe you didn't add your libs to your artifact

`File | Project Structure|Artifacts`

And then you need to add all your libs to the artifacts

Comment: There is no problem showing in the directory that you mentioned, and the local JARs no problem, all the errors happened with JARs that come from Gradle, and actually I can call the method from these JARs, but when I run or make the project, there comes the errors.

Comment: @Flyingun It looks like your out don't have all the Jars, you need add your JARS in your artifacts

Comment: @Flyingun Yes, I think so

Comment: en haha bu yong xie

Answer (score 0):

When you use Gradle to build projects outside IntelliJ, you probably could use `idea` plugin for gradle. Then when you want your IDE to be in sinc just run `gradle idea` which will update your .iml .ipr. .iws files with added artifacts.